# Why convert from RGB to YCrCb color space

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, color-space

I happen to come across this part when I was trying to implement a computer vision paper for segmenting objects. Can someone please give me benefit/favorable scenarios that we need/should covert image to YCrCb color space?

Comment: It can be usefull when segmenting images as the YCrCb color space is more lighting invariant then the RGB colorspace, and therefor it is easier to segment the image using a threshold

Comment: basic skin tone segmentation is an example

Answer (score 7):

YCrCb is one of multiple colour models that separate intensity from colour information. This has various applications.

One important application and kind of the reason why YCrCb was introduced is transmission of colour TV signals. RGB is quite redundant and humans are more sensitive to intensity than to colour information. So you can save a lot of bandwidth if you transmit the intensity in high resolution and colour in lower resolution. The same and maybe today the most important appliation is JPEG compression.

Another application: Histogram equalization or similar image enhancement techniques. You couldn't just apply this to RGB because changing RGB ratios would result in weird colour changes. So you only change the contrast of the intensity information and then re-convert it back to RGB.

Just do a websearch to find out more details.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about it, is that R,G and B are correlated. A color transform works like a rotation along one color axis (more obvious with some reversible transforms IMO) with the goal to reduce the coefficients of the 2 other colors. As a result, one channel contains more information (Luma) than the other 2 (Chroma). For compression, it is not unusual to downsample the Chroma channels by 2 (reducing the size of the color plan by 4) with very little visual loss.
In your case, it may be sufficient to process only the Luma channel.